# Azure nodejs dist directory "Error: EBUSY" or files silently not overriden

Tags: node.js, windows, azure

We have a nodejs - express, angular app.  The express app and Angular app are built separately, and the Angular is added into a `static/` directory under the express app.  In this formation, both are moved into a dist directory to be run using node.  It is deployed to Azure and runs under a Windows server (not my choice).

1. If the deploy script deletes the `dist/` directory it fails with

   ```
   ...
   remote: > bottal@1.0.0 clear:dist D:\home\site\wwwroot
   remote: > rimraf dist
   remote:
   remote: D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\rimraf\bin.js:47
   remote:       throw er
   remote:       ^
   remote:
   remote: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist'
   ```
2. If the dist directory is not deleted then the deploy silently fails by not overwriting the files.

Is there a best way to write such apps?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in 2 ways.

1. Delete the directory in the Azure `deploy.sh` (specified in `.deployment` file)
2. Instead change to using `zip` deploys instead of `git local` (whoops, I didn't say that above).

Both solve the problem, however what made the `zip` deploy the solution was because the `npm install` (download and install of dependencies) seemed almost instant compared to when being performed in a `git local` deploy.  We were in a bit of a  hurry to keep moving forward (after wasting so much time on what should not have been a problem) that I didn't put any investigation time in to this.  It would be interesting to know if it is true, however.d

Comment: NOTE that I've since discovered that the reason the `zip deploy` is instant is because it *ISN'T* running an `npm install`.  The expectation is that your site is ready to go (ie. you run the install and build before the zip deploy).  You can use `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` (see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#enabledisable-build-actions-preview).  However in the time i allocated to this, i could not get it to work.